# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED : Nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, bootstrap-4

I have a `bootstrap` form for email services for `angular 6` app and `nodejs`, I am using `nodemailer` for sendemail in my app, unfortunatelly does not work. I ma getting the following error:

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED : :3000/contact/send:1`

here is the form

```
 <form [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate>
    <div class="message">
      <h3> Write to us </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="form__top">
      <div class="form__left">
        <div class="form__group">
          <input class="form__input form__input--name" type="text"   formControlName="name" placeholder="name" #name>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].invalid && (angForm.controls['name'].dirty || angForm.controls['name'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].errors.required">
            Name is required.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
          <input class="form__input form__input--email" type="email"  formControlName="email" placeholder="email" #email>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['email'].invalid && (angForm.controls['message'].dirty || angForm.controls['message'].touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['message'].errors.required">
            message is required.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form__right">
        <div class="form__group">
          <textarea class="form__input form__input--textarea" placeholder="Message" formControlName="message"  #message
            rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['message'].invalid && (angForm.controls['message'].dirty || angForm.controls['message'].touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['message'].errors.required">
            message is required.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <flash-messages></flash-messages>
    <div class="form__down">
      <div class="form__group">
        <button (click)="sendMail(name.value, email.value, message.value)" [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid"  class="form__input form__input--submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">SEND MESSAGE
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
```

Here is contact,js (node mailer settings and routes)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

router.get('/send', (req, res) => {
    const outputData = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>  
      <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>
  `;

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        secure: false,
        port: 25,
        auth: {
            user: 'MY EMAIL',
            pass: 'THE PASSWORD'
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    let HelperOptions = {
        from: '"MYNAME" <MYEMAIL,
        to: 'MYEMAIL',
        subject: 'Majeni Contact Request',
        text: 'Hello',
        html: outputData
    };



    transporter.sendMail(HelperOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log("The message was sent!");
        console.log(info);
    });

});
module.exports = router;
```

here is the server js.

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
// Port Number
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
// Run the app by serving the static files
// in the dist directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/majeni/dist/majeni')));
// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//routes
const contact = require('./app/routes/contact');
app.use('/contact', contact);
// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());
// If an incoming request uses
// a protocol other than HTTPS,
// redirect that request to the
// same url but with HTTPS
const forceSSL = function () {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {
      return res.redirect(
        ['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join('')
      );
    }
    next();
  }
}

// Instruct the app
// to use the forceSSL
// middleware
app.use(forceSSL());

// For all GET requests, send back index.html
// so that PathLocationStrategy can be used
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/majeni/dist/majeni/index.html'));
});

// Start Server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port '+port);
  });
```

**UPDATE**

Here is service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Jsonp } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  sendEmail(name, email, message) {
    const uri = 'http://localhost:3000/contact/send';
    const obj = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      message: message,
    };
    return this.http.post(uri, obj);
  }
}
```

What is  missing in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED : :3000/contact/send:1`

Your error means your client application is Unable to connect to your nodejs server.

## Fix

Your code :

```
const uri = 'http://localhost:3000/contact/send';
```

Will work if nodejs server is running on port 3000 on localhost.

Comment: Your right, but now I have the following error  `home:1 Failed to load http://localhost:3000/contact/send: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access `  what do I need to change in my codes?

Comment: New issue, new question. Particularly if you’ve accept this as the answer to this question :)

Comment: @msbit here u go boss https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068069/angular-6-and-nodejs-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else getting this error.
Check that your NodeJS is not crashing.  If a previous request causes your NodeJS server to crash or restart this is the same error on subsequent requests.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest reasons to have such issue is to forget to start the backend app like in my case  I tried to login my reactjs forgetting to run my backend app, so make sure every time to start all the apps

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.   :5001/auth/jwt/login:1
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your spring boot project is also running with angular project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check your backend server port like this `http://localhost:**5000**/` and same port number using in your API to fetch the data in frontend like this `http://localhost:**5000**/books/${id}`